# C++: Is this a valid constant member function?

Tags: c++, methods, constants, member

I'm currently working on a c++ class. The purpose of the class is to do some http queries. You create an instance specifying

- destination url
- some other parameters

With this instance, you can call a method called "getChildren" which connects to the HTTP server, executes a query and returns a list of children. So basically, it looks similar to this:

```
class HttpRequest
{
   public:
   // omitted constructor, ...
   const std::list<Child> getChildren() {
      // do the http query
      // build a list
      return(list);
   }
}
```

The list which is returned by "getChildren" might change for each call - depending on other actions done on the HTTP server. Now what's your opinion: How shall I declare the method:

- `const std::list<Child> getChildren();`
- `const std::list<Child> getChildren() const;`

It will compile in both ways, since "getChildren" doesn't modify HttpRequest.

Thanks for your help,
Uli

Answer (score 3):

> - `const std::list<Child> getChildren();`
> - `const std::list<Child> getChildren() const;`
>
> It will compile in both ways, since "getChildren" doesn't modify HttpRequest.

1. No, it will not compile both ways. (If it would, what would that difference be there for?) 
   The second form is required to call `getChildren()` for `const HttpRequest` objects (or references or pointers):

   ```
   void f(const HttpRequest& req)
   {
      const std::list<Child>& list = req.getChildren(); // requires const
      // ...
   }
   ```

   This would require the trailing `const`.
2. The top-level `const` on the return type (`const std::list<Child>`) makes no difference at all. The returned object is an rvalue. All you can do with it is to make a copy or bind it to a `const std::list<Child>&` - no matter whether it's `const` or not.
3. You very likely do not want to copy such lists to be copied each time `getChildren()` is called, so you should return a *reference*:

   ```
   const std::list<Child>& getChildren() const;
   ```

   (Of course, if there is asynchrony involved, you might want to copy, rather than hand out references to a potentially asynchronously changing object.)
4. You can overload based on the trailing `const`. Given that, you could have two versions: one for changing the list and one for getting a `const` list reference:

   ```
   const std::list<Child>& getChildren() const;
         std::list<Child>& getChildren();
   ```

   I wouldn't know whether this makes any sense in your case.

Comment: In this case, copying is likely a non-issue - if the list is a reasonable size, then the bit of overhead spent copying compared to the tmie spend making an http request is likely negligible, and make for simpler code.  To return a reference, HttpRequest would have to store a copy and he'd have to be careful not to destroy the HttpRequest object before he was done with the list ...

Comment: That's ignoring NRVO and C++11's r-value constructors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback and explanations. In fact, I'm currently refactoring the method - I inherited it from other developers. Before, it used to return references. But unfortunately, the objects are stored in local variables so this is probably not a good way to do it. So: I'm keeping the "copy" for now. Maybe later I'll use something like smart pointers. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

My initial gut reaction here is that if it's hard to decide, we should look at the function in more detail. Also since the `HttpRequest` state isn't mutated, and since it may return a different value each time, perhaps the function shouldn't be a member at all. It seems that it might make more sense as a non-member, non-friend that makes use of the `HttpRequest` to perform its work and return a value. Then the const-semantics are clear.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Unfortunately, the situation here is tricky. We do have more than one `HttpRequest`. We a class hierarchy based on `HttpRequest` and each of the derived classes has a method `getChildren`. Some of them return the value of a member variable which is filled in at object creation time. Others do the http query at the time when `getChildren` is called. For the first group, I think the current declaration fits pretty well. For the other group, it might be different. I'll think about your proposal... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A general rule of thumb is declare a member function to be `const` if you can. If `getChildren` makes some modification that appears to change the state of the `HttpRequest` object it's called on (even if it doesn't actually change the state) it's possible you should declare it non-const to avoid confusing people. But otherwise, it should be `const`.

As an aside, I understand the logic of why you're declaring the return value to be `const`. I would still suggest you not do that. With C++11 and move constructors and such, it's actually very useful (and more accurate) for it to be non-const.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'll think about the `const` of the return value (... the copy).

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to make sure that the function does not change the state of the HttpRequest object, then you want `std::list<Child> getChildren() const`. There is no reason to make the `std::list` constant, unless you return a reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Currently, I'm thinking about returning the list by reference. If I decide not to do this (... and keep the copy), then I'll remove the `const`.